# associative arrays as selectors and values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to implement associative arrays as Selectors and Values.

I have an array

```
   var obj = { surgeon:1, asstSurgeon:2, anesthe:3, nurse:4, scrub:5,....... };
```

I am able to implement like this.

```
$("#surgeon").click(function(){
   $("$hiddenvariable").val(1);
});

$("#asstSurgeon").click(function(){
  $("$hiddenvariable").val(2);
});

................,
```

Can anyone help me how can i reduce the code.

Is there any other way to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with jQuery `$.each`

```
$.each (obj, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).click(function(){
       $("$hiddenvariable").val(value);
    });
 });
```

or Using `for..in` and `.on`. (Above method is better than below)

```
for (var i in obj) {
   $("#" + i).on('click', {i: obj[i]}, function(e){
       $("$hiddenvariable").val(e.data.i);
   });
}
```

Comment: So `i` is global and you don't want to filter prototype properties? Use `for (var p in o) if (o.hasOwnProperty(p))`.

Comment: Your first example won't work. The handlers are all referencing the same `i` variable. The second solution you added will work.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
$.each(obj, function(type, i) {
    $('#' + type).click(function() { $('#hiddenvariable').val(i); });
});
```

Comment: You probably meant `$('#' + type)`?

Answer (score 0):

Write a closure function in javascript, associate button ids with your closure variables and a common selector class

then use jquery

```
$(".selector").click(function(e){
    $("#hiddenfield").val(Closure.object[e.id]);
});
```

closure...

```
function Closure() = {}
Closure.object = {
    surgeon:1, asstSurgeon:2, anesthe:3, nurse:4, scrub:5
}
```

Comment: I think selecting by a class, then using the ID of the element in the handler to look up the value is a good idea. But why on earth did you create a function called `Closure`, only to assign a property to the Function object that has the ID/value map? Why wouldn't you just use a plain object like in the question?

Comment: its a good practice to use closures than a plain variables... you can use them like a object... add dynamic variables to it... and validations... etc...

Comment: That's not what a closure is. What you have is just a Function object to which you're assigning a property. You could do the same thing with a plain object, and it would be no different.